# Calling method on child class from parent class method (Objective-c 2.0)

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, methods

I have experience with object-oriented programming however this situation is unfamiliar for some reason. Consider the following Objective-c 2.0 code:

```
@interface A : NSObject
@end

@implementation A
- (void) f {
    [self g];
}
@end

@interface B : A
@end

@implementation B
- (void) g {
    NSLog(@"called g...");
}
@end
```

Is this the correct way to call a method on a child class from a method in the parent class? What happens if another child class doesn't implement method `g`? Perhaps there's a better way to solve this like an abstract method in the parent class `A`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending message to child from parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351937/sending-message-to-child-from-parent)

Comment: Also see: [Call subclass method from its superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515582/call-subclasss-method-from-its-superclass)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key is to have a method in the parent class that may be overriden in the child class.

```
@interface Dog : NSObject
- (void) bark;
@end

@implementation Dog
- (void) bark {
    NSLog(@"Ruff!");
}
@end

@interface Chihuahua : Dog
@end

@implementation Chihuahua
- (void) bark {
    NSLog(@"Yipe! Yipe! Yipe!");
}
@end
```

You see, your child class will override the parent method with its own implementation.  You might see it used like this:

```
Dog *someDog = [Chihuahua alloc] init] autorelease];
[someDog bark];
```

Output: `Yipe! Yipe! Yipe!`

Comment: Makes sense. Does `bark` need to be declared in the parent class interface?

Comment: `bark` should be declared in your interface.  Yes.

Comment: There may be a different situation where you actually do wish to call a different method such as what you've described.  For example, you may want to use a template pattern: [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), like if you want to call `bark` as in my example, however, bark would then in turn call some internal methods which will then be overridden by child class, sorta like Squeegy's example.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement `g` in the parent class, but make it do nothing.  This way it can be called without error, but still can be overridden.

```
@interface A : NSObject
@end

@implementation A
- (void) f {
    [self g];
}
- (void) g {} // Does nothing in baseclass
@end

@interface B : A
@end

@implementation B
- (void) g {
    NSLog(@"called g...");
}
@end
```

Or you check for the method on the object before executing it.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(g)]) {
  [self performSelector:@selector(g) withObject:nil];
}
```

But that can get pretty ugly.

Comment: The compiler fires off warnings though, doesn't it? Since the compile thinks it knows that the class of `self` doesn't implement that method?